# A has a group inverse if and only if its index is 1

Tags: linear-algebra, generalized-inverse

Prove that, if $A$ is a square matrix,

> $A$ has a group inverse if and only if its index is  1

### Definitions:

A matrix $G$ is said to be group inverse of $A$ if it satisfies,
$$AGA=A$$
$$GAG=G$$
$$AG=GA$$

Index $1$, means that rank($A$)=rank($A^2$).

### Work done:

One way is easy, since, $\rho(A)=\rho(
AGA)=\rho(GAA)\leq \rho(A^2)\leq\rho(A)$ where $\rho$ represents rank.

And for the otherway round, if $rank(A)=rank(A^2)$ then their column spaces are same.
But further how to proceed??

Any hint will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I will express this in terms of endomorphisms of a finite dimensional vector space $V$. Assume $f\colon V\to V$ is such that $\dim\operatorname{im}(f)=\dim\operatorname{im}(f^2)$. Since $\operatorname{im}(f^2)\subseteq\operatorname{im}(f)$ and the dimensions are finite and equal, we have $\operatorname{im}(f)=\operatorname{im}(f^2)$. We know that $f$ restricts to an automorphism $\varphi\colon\operatorname{im}(f)\to\operatorname{im}(f)$, since it take $\operatorname{im}(f)$ surjectively to $\operatorname{im}(f^2)=\operatorname{im}(f)$ and surjective endomorphisms on finite dimensional vector spaces are automorphisms.

Now take any complement $U$ of $\operatorname{im}(f)$, that is $V = \operatorname{im}(f) \oplus U$, and let
\begin{align*}
g\colon V = \operatorname{im}(f) \oplus U &\longrightarrow V, \\
(v,w) &\longmapsto \varphi^{-1}(v).
\end{align*}

Now we can verify that
\begin{align*}
f\circ g\circ f &= f,\\
g\circ f\circ g &= g,\\
f\circ g &= g\circ f.
\end{align*}

Comment: Perhaps this can be formulated a little more nicely in terms of quotient spaces.

Comment: I guess that would make it even harder to extract the statement for matrices..

Comment: I suppose that's fair

Comment: It is also notable that this is equivalent to saying that $A$ is similar to a matrix of the form
$$
\pmatrix{A' & 0\\0&0}
$$
where $A'$ is invertible.